# Problems when setting up Heroku for a Ruby app - 2 conflicting Ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am following this instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#local-workstation-setup

All fine until I try to run:

```
foreman start
```

And I get this back:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:4:in `':
>   It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
>   To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

In order to fix it I run:

```
brew install libyaml
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

Then again:

```
foreman start
```

and nothing has been solved. Same error. Googling around I have seen that the problem could be having 2 conflicting ruby versions. 
I run:

```
which -a ruby
```

> /Users/jacoposcotti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby
>   /usr/bin/ruby

Should I remove one? How?

---

output of:

```
rvm list
```

=>

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: add the output of `rvm list`

Comment: added, anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a faulty Yosemite DP1 installed on my Mac, I killed it with fire and reinstalled everything. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p481
```

and use whenever you want to use `ruby-2.0.0`